# Automatically adding bold to numbers in forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

So I'd like a script that after sending a form it would add   to numbers added in input form.

E.G.

```
Ability power ratio increased to <b>0.8</b> from <b>0.5</b>.
<b>20%</b> and <b>40/50/60/80</b>
```

I don't really know the logic behind script like that. I could possibly use substr() and check letter by letter first of all if it is a number or character. I'm sorry this question is so blunt but I have just no idea how to tackle this problem.

```
<form name="second_form" id="second_form" action="#" method="POST">         
    <div class="Change">
            <textarea type="text" size="20" rows="3" cols="50" maxlength="500" name="SpellDescription[]" placeholder="Enter Description" required>
</textarea>
            </div>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Why would you be doing this with PHP rather than JavaScript or something similar to that?

Comment: @099 Added tags sorry about that

Comment: Use CSS, create these number fields with a specific class and then set that CSS class to be `font-weight:bold`

Comment: Worth remembering, since it's front end question, that `<b>` tags are deprecated.

Comment: Could be span with font-weight my problem is to automatically detect numbers etc I don't want to have put manually spans with classes since there is a lot of text i have to go through

Comment: @AedixRhinedale. No, `<b>` tag is no longer deprecated: it had been temporarily deprecated because it was purely _presentational_, but now is considered to have a _semantic_ purpose.  Look at [W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/b.html#b), chapter "Changes in HTML5".

Comment: @cFreed thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
echo preg_replace( '/([0-9]+)\.?(\/?[0-9\.?]*)*%?/', '<strong>$0</strong>', 'test 0.1 this 5 test 0/1/2/3 5% 50% 5.5% 5   % . / 5/5.5/3/1.5/35.5/1.75');
```

You can try it out yourself here aswell: [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)
And to perfect the regex (as you can do so much with it), please fiddle arround on [regexr](http://regexr.com/)

**Edited the regex as suggested by caCtus, thanks for your input!**

Comment: This regex isn't perfect : "0.5." is matched (ending `.`) and "20%" is not. Also `.` and `/` alone are matched. I tried `[0-9/]+\.?[0-9]+%?`, might need some other improvements. http://regexr.com/3blks

Comment: The thing is that I gave more like a suggestion, what to match is up to the user. I agree that the regex is simple, I just didn't have that much time :p I'll add the regexr site to the answer.

Comment: Sorry if my comment looked like I wanted to disapprove your answer, I only wanted to complete it. :)

Comment: Oh no you're not, after all this board is meant to help out fellow developers. See my edited answer~

Comment: @caCtus I've tried '[0-9/]+\.?[0-9]+%?' but I get an error preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '+'

Comment: @higeath I tried my updated preg in PHP fiddle, doesn't that work? It was simply missing an escape I think.

Comment: @Xyv Works like a charm thank you both guys, really helped me a lot here !

Comment: @Xyv one more thing /[0-9\/]+\.?[0-9]+%?/ how can I target also regular numbers 0-9 ive tried /[0-9\/?]+\.?[0-9]+%?/  with no luck

Comment: @higeath  hey,  yes, replace the last plus `+` with a star `*`

Comment: Please see my update (lol again -m-), It's getting a little messy, but covers anything I could think of so far!